# Issue with system.reflection, GetFields not returning everything

Tags: c#, oop, system.reflection, bindingflags

Im having a bit of an issue with System.Reflection. Please see the attached code:

```
class Program
{
    public static FieldInfo[] ReflectionMethod(object obj)
    {
        var flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly;
        return obj.GetType().GetFields(flags);
    }
        static void Main()
    {
        var test = new Test() { Id = 0, Age = 12, Height = 24, IsSomething = true, Name = "Greg", Weight = 100 };
        var res = ReflectionMethod(test);
    }
}

    public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public bool IsSomething { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int CalculationResult => Weight * Height;

    public Test()
    {

    }
}
```

It seems as though the getfields method is not getting the calculated property CalculationResult. I'm assuming there is another flag I need to use, but I can't figure out which one it is.

Thanks in advance and I'll happily provide more info if necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because it is a property and not a field.

`=>` is a syntactic sugar for a getter which is a property. So it is equivelant to:

```
public int CalculationResult 
{ 
   get 
   { 
      return Weight * Height; 
   }
}
```

So you need to use `.GetProperties(flags)`

Comment: and thank you for introducing me to the phrase "syntactic sugar", I'm going to use it more in conversation

Answer (score 2):

Well, analyzing this line of code :

```
public int CalculationResult => Weight * Height;
```

Which can also be simplified to (without C# 6.0 syntactic sugar) :

```
public int CalculationResult {get { return Weight*Height; } }
```

Compiler doesn't create backing field because it's not auto-property and that's why it is not among the fields retrieved from class by reflection calls.

If you change it to `public int CalculationResult { get; }` it will create the field and it will show up in the list.